# Writes to FrameBuffer /dev/fb0 do not seem to change graphics screen

Tags: ubuntu, framebuffer

In attempting to write directly to the graphics frame buffer /dev/fb0 , (Ubuntu 12.04) , the graphics screen does not change.

Has Ubuntu 12.04 invalidated the use of /dev/fb0 , or does it need to be activated in some way ?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail how you do the "writing"? (script, program, command line, etc)

Comment: @John I tried the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722301/writing-to-frame-buffer) with the same results: nothing appears on the screen. I also tried shutting off the GUI, and switching to an alternate console with Ctrl+Alt+F1, but nothing appears on the screen. I looked at using SDL, but it uses BitBlt for everything which will be too slow for individual pixel writes to the screen.

Comment: Is it possible the screen re-fresh rate so fast that "cover" your screen update.

Comment: @John No , the area size being written to the screen was 200x200 pixels and there was not even a flicker. The driver is non-accelerated and you would see that flash if it were actually writing to the screen. During the various tests of turning various things on and off in Ubuntu , somewhere along the line /dev/fb0 vanished , but the thing that made me suspicious that Ubuntu is not using /dev/fb0 at all is because the GUI was present and functioned normally without /dev/fb0. I didn't even notice until when trying to open /dev/fb0 using the test program it failed to open the file.

Answer (score 5):

Had to do a 2nd `ioctl()` to ACTIVATE the frame buffer, then it worked.

```
/* Refresh buffer manually */
vi.activate |= FB_ACTIVATE_NOW | FB_ACTIVATE_FORCE;
if(0 > ioctl(fd, FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO, &vi)) {
  printf("Failed to refresh\n");
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as 'accepted' so everyone knows that you have solved your problem.