# Why reading from and writing to framebuffer shows no effect ?

Tags: command-line, devices, framebuffer

I read a very short description of how to make a Screenshot by making use of the file which represents the framebuffer /dev/fb0.

in order to write the screen content:

```
cat /dev/fb0 > file
```

in order to restore the screenshot:

```
cat file > /dev/fb0
```

I did so, but nothing happened, not even a short blink, so I find a possible hint to an answer:

[Writes to FrameBuffer /dev/fb0 do not seem to change graphics screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58420/writes-to-framebuffer-dev-fb0-do-not-seem-to-change-graphics-screen)

But, there was only an answer I did not understand which required knowledge in C programming language (at least the Code looked to me like C )

Comment: +1 making a screenshot from the terminal without using obscure utilities is certainly worth consideration.